# Python and creating a list wth a pattern - x1, x2, ... x100

Tags: python

I want to create a list using an iterator that will go to 100,000

['guid:0','guid:2', .....'guid:100000']

Python is the most python method to do this?  A one liner...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

python2: `['guid:%d' % i for i in xrange(0, 100002, 2)]`

python3: `['guid:%d' % i for i in range(0, 100002, 2)]`

Comment: Might be worth adding the `step` parameter to `range` given that OP's example skips the odd numbers